# ORDER BY DISTINCT CASE FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, distinct

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22253/3)**

SQL Server 2012 schema setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Course
(
     CourseID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,CourseName NVARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Session
(
     SessionID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,CourseID  INT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE SessionTime
(
    ,SessionID INT
    ,DayOfWeek TINYINT --Sunday(0), Monday(1), ..., Saturday(6)
)

INSERT INTO COURSE(CourseName) VALUES('Science 10'), ('Bio 30')
INSERT INTO Session(CourseID) VALUES(1), (2)

INSERT INTO SessionTime(SessionID, DayOfWeek)
VALUES(1, 5), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 4),
      (2, 1), (2, 3)
```

Query:

```
SELECT   C.CourseName
        ,S.SessionID
        ,STUFF(
                (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CASE 
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 0 THEN 'Su'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 1 THEN 'M'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 2 THEN 'T'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 3 THEN 'W'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 4 THEN 'Th'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 5 THEN 'F'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 6 THEN 'Sa'
                                        END
                FROM SessionTime ST
                WHERE ST.SessionID = S.SessionID
                --ORDER BY DayOfWeek
                FOR XML PATH (''))
            ,1,2,'') AS DaysOfWeek
FROM Session S
INNER JOIN Course C on S.CourseID = C.CourseID
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22253/3/0):

```
| COURSENAME | SESSIONID |   DAYSOFWEEK |
|------------|-----------|--------------|
| Science 10 |         1 | F, Su, T, Th |
|     Bio 30 |         2 |         M, W |
```

Desired results:

```
| COURSENAME | SESSIONID |   DAYSOFWEEK |
|------------|-----------|--------------|
| Science 10 |         1 | Su, T, Th, F | *Order of DaysOfWeek has changed.
|     Bio 30 |         2 |         M, W |
```

I want to order the DayOfWeek (Su,M,T,W,Th,F,Sa) before I `STUFF` them all together but my attempts have resulted in the following error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

I've tried the following:

- `ORDER BY 1` orders the days alphabetically not (Su,M,T,W,Th,F,Sa)
- `ORDER BY DayOfWeek` results in the aforementioned error message
- `ORDER BY DayOfWeekCase` adding an `AS DayOfWeekCase` to the `END` of the `CASE` but that changes the way `FOR XML` returns the days

How can I order the `DayOfWeek` before `STUFF`ing it together?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `DISTINCT`, try using `GROUP BY`. Then, you could do `ORDER BY DayOfWeek`.

```
SELECT   C.CourseName
        ,S.SessionID
        ,STUFF(
                (SELECT ', ' + CASE 
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 0 THEN 'Su'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 1 THEN 'M'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 2 THEN 'T'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 3 THEN 'W'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 4 THEN 'Th'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 5 THEN 'F'
                                            WHEN ST.DayOfWeek = 6 THEN 'Sa'
                                        END
                FROM SessionTime ST
                WHERE ST.SessionID = S.SessionID
                GROUP BY st.DayOfWeek
                ORDER BY DayOfWeek              
                FOR XML PATH (''))
            ,1,2,'') AS DaysOfWeek
FROM Session S
INNER JOIN Course C on S.CourseID = C.CourseID
```